# Keep Firebase User logged In in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am new to flutter and I am developing an app where I want to provide users with the Keep me logged In functionality and I was searching for a way to keep the firebase User to be logged in even if the user closes the app. I found many ways using shared Preference but those were not related to firebase and does not explain how the firebase user will stay logged in and how the user data from firebase is fetched if the user is not entering his email and password using the sign-in function. I am confused about it. I will really appreciate any help, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do to is to check if a user if the user is authenticated or not.if current user is authenticated then show Homescreen else login. This can be done with `Firebase`.

Here is sample code:

```
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
if(user != null){
  // navigate to home page
}
else
{
// log in 
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for me.